# Морфемный разбор слова "баночка"

Tags: морфемы

'бан' - корень, 'оч' и "к" - суффиксы, 'а' - окончание, правильно?

Гугл выдаёт, что 'баноч' корень О_о, в другом месте вообще суффикс один - 'очк'
Как же всё-таки правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Банк/а - баноч/к/а

О - беглая гласная, корень БАНОЧ, К - уменьшительно-ласкательный суффикс.

Comment: Спасибо! А не посоветуете, София, толковый учебный материал, где это всё очень подробно разжёвывается? Везде одно и тоже - минимум материала и легкие примеры.

Comment: При проведении морфемного анализа я пользуюсь словообразовательными словарями (Тихонов, например, или другие), там приводится словообразовательная цепочка для каждого слова. Также очень помогает "Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц" Ефремовой.  В этих источниках можно найти и базовую теорию, и практическое решение любой задачи.